# How Do I Create A Binary Search Tree In Java?

Tags: java, binary-search-tree, nodes

I'm working on a homework assignment in my OOP class and am having some trouble seeing where I'm going awry. I keep getting NullPointerExceptions even though I'm not doing anything with any nodes which is confusing me.
I'm trying to create an insert method that takes a generic object parameter and returns nothing - this is what I have at the moment:

```
public class BinarySearchTree<T extends Comparable <T>> implements BinaryTree<T> {
    class Node {
       public T data;
       public Node left;
       public Node right;
       
       public Node(T newObject) {
          this.data = newObject;
          this.left = null;
          this.right = null;
       }
       
       public void insert(T newObject) {
          if (root == null) {
             root = new Node(newObject);
          } else if (newObject.compareTo(root.data) < 0) {
             root.left.insert(newObject);
          } else if (newObject.compareTo(root.data) > 0) {
             root.right.insert(newObject);
          }
       }
    }
    
    private Node root;
    
    public void insert(T newObject) {
       this.insert(newObject);
    }
}
```

However, by running the following, I keep getting thrown NullPointerExceptions:
`bstExample.insert(5);`

I've looked at a bunch of YouTube videos, reread through my textbook section regarding binary (search) trees, and reached out to classmates for support but haven't come up with anything.

Comment: The exception has LOADS more info - like the line number the problem is on. You should look at it and if you still need help you should include all of that in your question.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Have you searched Stack Overflow?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it/218510   Note some of the responses include information about using a stack trace.  Here is a question specifically about reading a stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

With `insert` as a instance method of `Node`, there is an issue with inserting into an empty tree, as `this.root` would be `null` and you cannot call any methods on `null`. Similarly, calling `root.left.insert(newObject);` would not work when `root.left` is `null`. You would you need to construct the new `Node` first to set as `root.left`.

It is much simpler to implement a helper `insert` method inside the `BinarySearchTree` class itself.

```java
public void insert(T newObject) {
   this.root = insert(this.root, newObject);
}

private Node insert(Node curr, T obj) {
    if (curr == null)
        return new Node(obj);
    else {
        final int comp = obj.compareTo(curr.data);
        if (comp < 0)
            curr.left = insert(curr.left, obj);
        else if (comp > 0) 
            curr.right = insert(curr.right, obj);
        return curr;
    }
}
```